# Optimizing Slow, Indexed Select MySql Query

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I am trying to execute a simple select query using a table indexed on src_ip like so:

SELECT * FROM netflow_nov2 WHERE `src_IP`=3111950672;

However this is not completed after even 4 or 5 hours.  I need the response to be in the range of a few seconds.  I am wondering how I can optimize it so this is the case.

Also note that source ip’s were converted to integers using the built in SQL command.

Other information about the table:
The table contains netflow data parsed from nfdump.  I am using the table to get information about specific IP addresses.  In other words, basically only queries like the above will be used.

Here is the relevant info as given by SHOW TABLE STATUS for this table:

```
Rows: 4,205,602,143 (4 billion)
Data Length: 426,564,911,104 (426 GB)
Index Length: 57,283,706,880 (57 GB)
```

Information about the system:
Hard disk: ~2TB, using close to maximum
RAM: 64GB

my.cnf file:
see gist: https://gist.github.com/ashtonwebster/e0af038101e1b42ca7e3

Table structure:

```
   mysql> DESCRIBE netflow_nov2;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date      | datetime         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| duration  | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| protocol  | varchar(16)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| src_IP    | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| src_port  | int(2)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dest_IP   | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dest_port | int(2)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| flags     | varchar(8)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Tos       | int(4)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| packets   | int(8)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bytes     | int(8)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pps       | int(8)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bps       | int(8)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Bpp       | int(8)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Flows     | int(8)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
15 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I have additional info about the indexes and the results of explain, but briefly:
-The indexes are b-trees, and there are indexes for date, src_ip, and dest_ip, but only src_ip will really be used
-Based on the output of EXPLAIN, the src_ip index is being used for that particular query mentioned at the top

And the output of mysqltuner:
see gist: https://gist.github.com/ashtonwebster/cbfd98ee1799a7f6b323

SHOW CREATE TABLE output:

```
| netflow_nov2 | CREATE TABLE `netflow_nov2` (
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `protocol` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_IP` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_port` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_IP` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_port` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flags` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tos` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packets` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bytes` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pps` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bps` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bpp` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Flows` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `src_IP` (`src_IP`),
  KEY `dest_IP` (`dest_IP`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add 

SHOW CREATE TABLE `netflow_nov2` 

result

Comment: do you have index on src_IP field or its component index with some other fields?

Comment: @DmitryBezik show create table has been included at the bottom of the question. As you can see there is indeed an index on src_ip.  also, SHOW INDEXES OUTPUT: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyh6335c0uconh8/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-10%20at%2011.02.37%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Look into partitioning

Comment: @Mihai I like this idea.  What do you think I should partition based on?  Key? row id? Date?

Comment: If i knew i would have given an answer.Try here http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current table structure is optimized for random writes: records are placed on disk in the order of writes.

Unfortunately the only read pattern that is well supported by such a structure is a full-table scan.
Usage of non-covering secondary indices still results in a lot of random disk seeks which are killing performance.

The best reading performance is obtained when data is read in the same order as it is located on disk, which for InnoDB means in the primary key order.

A materialized view (another InnoDB table that has an appropriate primary key) could be a possible solution. In this case a primary key that starts with `src_IP` is required.

**upd:** The idea is to achieve data locality and avoid random disk IO, aiming for sequential reading. This means that your materialized view will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `netflow_nov2_view` (
  `row_id` bigint not null, -- see below
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `protocol` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_IP` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `src_port` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_IP` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_port` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flags` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tos` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packets` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bytes` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pps` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bps` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bpp` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Flows` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`src_IP`, `row_id`) -- you won't need other keys
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

where `row_id` has to be maintained by your materializing logic, since you don't have it in the original table (or you can introduce an explicit auto_increment field to your original table, it's how InnoDB handles it anyway).

The crucial difference is that now all data on the disk is placed in the primary key order, which means that once you locate the first record with a given 'src_IP' all other records can be obtained as sequentially as possible.

Depending on the way your data is written and adjacent application logic it can be accomplished either via triggers or by some custom external process.

If it is possible to sacrifice current write performance (or use some async queue as a buffer) then probably having a single table optimized for reading would suffice.

More on InnoDB indexing:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: Can you explain what a materialized view table might look like?  I imagine that each row index would be the src_ip and the values would be the id of the rows that they are stored in?  I am a bit confused regarding this, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SPLASHT0N Please see the post update, hope that helps.

Comment: I see that this would work but I worry that it will take a long time to create the indices.  Still, I see no other solution.  Thank you for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that reading the table *without* an index would take less than 5 hours.  But you do have a big table.  There are two "environmental" possibilities that would kill the performance:

- The table is locked by another process.
- The result set is huge (tens of millions of rows) and the network latency/processing time for returning the result set is causing the problem.

My first guess, though, is that the query is *not* using the index.  I missed this at first, but you have one multi-part index.  The *only* index this query can take advantage of is one where the first key is `src_IP`.  So, if you index is either `netflow_nov2(src_IP,  date, dest_ip)` or `netflow_nov2(src_IP, dest_ip, date)`, then you are ok.  If either of the other columns is first, then this index will not be used.  You can easily see what is happening by putting `explain` in front the query to see if the index is being used.

If this is a problem, create an index with `src_IP` as the first (or only) key in the index.

Comment: Mul does not mean composite index `If Key is MUL, the column is the first column of a nonunique index in which multiple occurrences of a given value are permitted within the column`

Comment: I am quite sure the index is being used.  The EXPLAIN command suggests that it is indeed being used: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6szvyi6kiflfn8/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-10%20at%2011.02.26%20AM.png?dl=0.  And yes, Mihai is correct in his assertion that these are not multipart keys but keys with non-unique values.  In fact, there may be millions of matches for each src_ip, which may be the problem.